# SQL Aggregation issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate, aggregation

I have two tables; Savings and Spend. What I need is both of them rolled up into one row by Month & Year, and Site/Location.

Tables are setup as followed. Data is obviously cleansed and please ignore the lovely structure for dates.

Spend Table

```html
Site# Region  Total Spend Month Year
52 Region1 $589.01 8 2015
52 Region1 $236.41 8 2015
52 Region1 $635.97 8 2015
52 Region1 $710.54 8 2015
52 Region1 $411.42 8 2015
52 Region1 $374.79 8 2015
52 Region1 $153.82 8 2015
52 Region1 $903.01 8 2015
52 Region1 $930.48 8 2015
52 Region1 $778.35 8 2015
52 Region1 $306.33 8 2015
52 Region1 $1,360 8 2015
52 Region1 $9,4292 8 2015
52 Region1 $6,7191 8 2015
52 Region1 $90.77 8 2015
52 Region1 $60.48 8 2015
52 Region1 $30.66 8 2015
52 Region1 $66.59 8 2015
52 Region1 $28.03 8 2015
52 Region1 $16.77 8 2015
52 Region1 $4,3851 8 2015
52 Region1 $244.07 8 2015
52 Region1 $987.81 8 2015
52 Region1 $2,7327 8 2015
52 Region1 $189.94 8 2015
52 Region1 $360.72 8 2015
52 Region1 $427.31 8 2015
52 Region1 $1,5069 8 2015
52 Region1 $987.81 8 2015
52 Region1 $1,7397 8 2015
52 Region1 $224.74 8 2015
52 Region1 $134.96 8 2015
52 Region1 $2,5456 8 2015
52 Region1 $124.53 8 2015
52 Region1 $1,9049 8 2015
52 Region1 $63.21 8 2015
52 Region1 $252.84 8 2015
52 Region1 $218.43 8 2015
52 Region1 $172.64 8 2015
52 Region1 $327.25 8 2015
52 Region1 $1,8732 8 2015
52 Region1 $788.03 8 2015
52 Region1 $693.72 8 2015
52 Region1 $205.68 8 2015
52 Region1 $18.70 8 2015
52 Region1 $122.09 8 2015
52 Region1 $136.91 8 2015
52 Region1 $2,0666 8 2015
52 Region1 $2,0967 8 2015
52 Region1 $618.57 8 2015
52 Region1 $179.06 8 2015
52 Region1 $16.28 8 2015
52 Region1 $2,2232 8 2015
52 Region1 $694.80 8 2015
52 Region1 $165.42 8 2015
52 Region1 $47.88 8 2015
52 Region1 $4.36 8 2015
52 Region1 $785.33 8 2015
52 Region1 $108.49 8 2015
52 Region1 $9.86 8 2015
52 Region1 $119.09 8 2015
52 Region1 $10.83 8 2015
52 Region1 $1,2097 8 2015
52 Region1 $75.55 8 2015
52 Region1 $4,7307 8 2015
52 Region1 $73.46 8 2015
52 Region1 $396.71 8 2015
52 Region1 $4.94 8 2015
52 Region1 $309.58 8 2015
52 Region1 $126.86 8 2015
52 Region1 $1,5295 8 2015
52 Region1 $104.03 8 2015
52 Region1 $2,8494 8 2015
52 Region1 $2,4338 8 2015
52 Region1 $644.40 8 2015
52 Region1 $23.20 8 2015
52 Region1 $171.45 8 2015
52 Region1 $1,6264 8 2015
52 Region1 $784.53 8 2015
52 Region1 $535.24 8 2015
52 Region1 $259.69 8 2015
52 Region1 $288.57 8 2015
52 Region1 $408.43 8 2015
52 Region1 $72.95 8 2015
52 Region1 $49.95 8 2015
52 Region1 $30.09 8 2015
52 Region1 $1,8848 8 2015
52 Region1 $315.33 8 2015
52 Region1 $1,3658 8 2015
52 Region1 $470.30 8 2015
52 Region1 $29,445 8 2015
52 Region1 $154.12 8 2015
52 Region1 $110.68 8 2015
52 Region1 $75.47 8 2015
52 Region1 $273.65 8 2015
52 Region1 $366.40 8 2015
52 Region1 $316.01 8 2015
```

Savings Table

```html
Month Year Site Region Total Savings
8 2015 52 Region1 $1,950.05
8 2015 52 Region1 $234.49
8 2015 52 Region1 $1,548.54
8 2015 52 Region1 $2,433.42
8 2015 52 Region1 $2,073.94
8 2015 52 Region1 $1,956.75
8 2015 52 Region1 $235.30
8 2015 52 Region1 $3,107.72
8 2015 52 Region1 $332.97
8 2015 52 Region1 $2,580.52
```

My expected output would be as follows

```html
Site# Region Month Year Total Savings Total Spend
52 Region1 8 2015 16453.7 109866.17
```

Obviously there is a lot more data here and my query is much longer than any example I can give due to data sensitivity.. but the query I was running is close to this

```html
SELECT

 [s].[Month],
 [s].[Year],
 [s].[Site],
 [s].[Region],
 SUM([s].[Total Savings]),

 SUM([sp].Total Spend)

FROM [Savings] AS [s]

 LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT
   [Total Spend]
   
  FROM [Spend]
  ) AS [sp]
  
  ON [s].[Month] = [sp].[Month]
  AND [s].[Year] = [sp].[Year]
  AND [s].[Site] = [sp].[Site]

  
  GROUP BY
   [s].[Month],
   [s].[Year],
   [s].[Site],
   [s].[Region]
```

Problem with the code is I'm getting a lot of unexpected aggregations.. and the values are being multiplied a lot. Sometimes I can get the savings to calculate correctly but its sum'ed on each line.

My question is what is the most appropriate way to combine data that is structured like this and be able to report on every column ( assuming they're not unique ). I know I could do a subquery for every single column but feel that is horrible practice.

TL;DR - I have two tables I need to join with aggregation, and be able to select all columns from both tables.

This is on Microsoft SQL via Tableau

EDIT

Just tried this query

```html
SELECT

    SUM(CAST([ms].[USD_SavingsAmt] AS decimal(38,2))) AS [Total Savings],
    SUM([s].[USD_SpendAmt]) AS [Total Spend],
    [ms].[MOR_Reporting_Year] AS [Year],
    [ms].[MOR_Reporting_Month] AS [Month],
    [ms].[Site#] AS [Site]


FROM [MonthlySavings_14637] AS [ms], [MonthlySpend_14637] AS [s]


    WHERE [ms].[MOR_Reporting_Year] = [s].[MOR_Reporting_Year]
    AND [ms].[MOR_Reporting_Month] = [s].[MOR_Reporting_Month]
    AND [ms].[Site#] = [s].[Site#]

 AND [s].[Site#] = '52'
 AND [ms].[MOR_Reporting_Month] = '8'
 AND [ms].[MOR_Reporting_Year] = '2015'
  
GROUP BY

    [ms].[MOR_Reporting_Year],
    [ms].[MOR_Reporting_Month],
    [ms].[Site#]
```

And got this result

```html
Site Month Total Savings Total Spend Year
52 8 1,596,008.90 1,098,661.65 2,015
```

The values are being duplicated.

TTG Guy, using your logic

```html
SELECT

   SUM([ms].[Total Savings]) AS [Total Savings],
    SUM([s].[USD_SpendAmt]) AS [Total Spend],
    [s].[MOR_Reporting_Year] AS [Year],
    [s].[MOR_Reporting_Month] AS [Month],
    [s].[Site#] AS [Site]


FROM [MonthlySpend_14637] AS [s]


 INNER JOIN 
  ( 
   SELECT 
    SUM([MonthlySavings_14637].[USD_SavingsAmt]) AS [Total Savings],
    [MonthlySavings_14637].[MOR_Reporting_Month] AS [Month],
    [MonthlySavings_14637].[MOR_Reporting_Year] AS [Year],
    [MonthlySavings_14637].[Site#] AS [Site]
    
   FROM [MonthlySavings_14637]
   
   GROUP BY [MOR_Reporting_Month], [MOR_Reporting_Year], [Site#]
  ) AS [ms]
  
 ON [ms].[Site]=[s].[Site#]
 AND [ms].[Month] = [s].[MOR_Reporting_Month]
 AND [ms].[Year] = [s].[MOR_Reporting_Year]


 WHERE 

  [s].[Site#] = '52'
 AND [s].[MOR_Reporting_Month] = '8'
 AND [s].[MOR_Reporting_Year] = '2015'
  

GROUP BY [s].[MOR_Reporting_Month], [s].[MOR_Reporting_Year], [s].[Site#]
```

I got

```html
Site Month Total Savings Total Spend Year
52 8 1,596,008.90 109,866.17 2,015
```

Spend is correct!

Comment: With your LEFT JOIN from Savings to Spend in your example, you seem to assume that your Savings table dictates which combinations of Region, Site, Month, and Year should appear, and that the combinations of these columns in your Spend table will always be a subset of those, or that you don't care about records in the Spend table that don't match on those columns to records in Savings.  Is that true?

Comment: It should be a full outer join to know which Region, Site, Month, Year combos did not either supply savings or spend data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that you said in a few places that you were having problems with a subquery, but this one seems to work fine for me:

```
SELECT sp.site#, sp.region,sp.month,sp.year,savingstotals.[total savings], sum([totalspend]) as [Total Spend]
FROM
spend sp
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT site, region, month, year , sum([total savings]) [total savings]
from savings
group by  site, region, month, year ) SavingsTotals ON
Savingstotals.site=sp.site#
AND Savingstotals.month=sp.month
AND Savingstotals.year=sp.year
AND Savingstotals.region=sp.region
group by sp.site#, sp.region,sp.month,sp.year, SavingsTotals.[total savings]
```

Comment: I must have misread your post. I don't see it anymore though. When I saw your answer you had SUM(total savings)..., SUM(totalspend) in the same select statement with no subquery.

Comment: no it was the same as you answer before i edited it..never mind

Comment: Your updated results does not follow my logic correctly.

Comment: Change
SUM([ms].[Total Savings]) AS [Total Savings],
to  just:
[ms].[Total Savings]

also, add 
, [s].[Total Savings]
to the end of your GROUP BY

Comment: Thanks for clarifying @vkp. I thought I was losing my mind.

Comment: That worked! Seriously felt like I tried that combination at some point haha. Perhaps both of us are losing our minds. Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: Full outer joined another table using the same logic and works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
([s_agg].[Month],
[s_agg].[Year],
[s_agg].[Site],
[s_agg].[Region],
[s_agg].[tot_sav],
[sp_agg].[tot_sp]
from (
select [s].[Month],
[s].[Year],
[s].[Site],
[s].[Region],
SUM([s].[Total Savings] [tot_sav]
FROM [Savings] AS [s]
GROUP BY
        [s].[Month],
        [s].[Year],
        [s].[Site],
        [s].[Region]
) AS [s_agg]
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT [Month],
       [Year],
       [Site],
       [Region],
       SUM([Total Spend]) [tot_sp]
FROM [Spend] AS [sp]
GROUP BY [sp].[Month],
       [sp].[Year],
       [sp].[Site],
       [sp].[Region]
) AS [sp_agg] 
    ON [s_agg].[Month] = [sp_agg].[Month]
    AND [s_agg].[Year] = [sp_agg].[Year]
    AND [s_agg].[Site] = [sp_agg].[Site]
```

Comment: I tried it this way but it was multiplying my sum by amount of rows causing an extremely large value. I feel the syntax is correct I'm just not sure whats going on..

Answer (score 0):

You could always UNION and them SUM them:

```
SELECT site, region, month, year, sum([total savings]) [total savings]
, sum([total spend]) [total spend]
 from (select site, region, month, year, [Total Savings] [Total Savings], 0 as [total spend]
from savings
UNION ALL
select site#, region, month, year, 0, [TotalSpend] [Total Savings]
from spend) unionsubquery
group by site, region, month, year
```

Comment: While I know this would work, both my live tables have far much more data in them that do not exist in both tables.

Comment: So you don't want the 0s, or you are concerned about performance?

Comment: Performance should be okay... I just don't want to have to alias a bunch of nulls to get the query to work. I could get the same result if I used a subquery on each column I'd think.